# Calculate the area and perimeter of a drawn style

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to know whether my idea for my final year project could be achieved or not. If its achievable please guide me with the relevant language and other frameworks etc. Big Help Guys. Here`s my idea.

I have a piece of paper (A4) on which I draw a circle. Once it is drawn I need to calculate the area and perimeter. In order to calculate the area and perimeter I move the mouse pointer on the image borders. Then the area and perimeter is calculated. Input of the image fed into the application via scanning or capturing as an image.

Please help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: its achievable. But this question is **way** too broad. come back with something concrete and you'll get help.

Comment: what you mean @Paul ? Info is not enough ?

Comment: what you've described so far is a (rather vague - atleast to me) description of your project. Point is, this task is about creating a UI, basic image-processing and loading of an image. So you'll have to take several steps like choosing a language, imageprocessing-library, unless you want to write that on your own, etc.. SO can help you with a more concrete problem like issues with an algorithm, but the design of the overall project is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the `BufferedImage` class and use the `.getRGB` method to get the individual pixels and use that to determine where the 'darker' pixels are and find the lines. Then it's just some relatively-simple filtering to filter out errant pixels and finally go through the curvature and put create a buncha points, out of which you can create your own `Circle` object and finally find whatever characteristics you want. But no, I don't think it will be easy.

And I'm not sure what you meant by "In order to calculate the area and perimeter I move the mouse pointer on the image borders."

Comment: Thanks pal. Meant by "In order to calculate the area and perimeter I move the mouse pointer on the image borders." is when you drag your mouse point on the drawn circle it should calculate and output the are and perimeter.

Comment: So what is the point of drawing the circle on the paper if you're just going to move the mouse over it?

Comment: Just think of case like you get an image of a car. So you cant draw it and check the calculation nuh. For that purpose

Comment: You said "I have a piece of paper (A4) on which I draw a circle. "

Comment: True true. That is for you to get an idea pal. any style.